# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "ReactCommon/callinvoker

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, react-native

npm -v  6.14.10

Hi, I have a project in React-Native. I would like to open it via xcode, but I have problems with the pods.

[Error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6KVV.jpg)

[Error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cxy6.jpg)

Comment: As stated in the error-message ... try to call `pod install --repo-update` ... cause they might be out of date...

Comment: He already did that, look at the first screen

Comment: are you try to install react or react-native, version you trying to install is wrong.. this might help to know the latest version - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native

Comment: I try but nothing !

Comment: @SureshThayu I try that 
+ react-native@0.63.4
removed 386 packages, updated 2 packages and audited 2817 packages in 23.087s

140 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

Comment: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/getting-started-with-react-native-in-2019-build-your-first-app-a41ebc0617e2 - this help for pre-requisites for env setup..

Comment: npm fund you can ignore, it is building now?

Comment: @SureshThayu The only command I haven't done is: (react-native init nameproject). For the rest I did everything. I updated, tried to fix all the errors that came out. The only one left is this.

Comment: Hello, thank you a everybody's for the answers. I fixed the problem. The simplest problems are the most difficult. xD I fix it by a update a node.js .